# How to filter the list based on generic property

Tags: c#, linq, uwp

I am trying to remove the hardcoding here while using the LINQ. 
Basically I have 10 properties and based on the selected property I want to filter the list.
Can someone help me removing this kind of hardcoding, is there a way to get the information of the property based on the "propertyName" string value and using the same while filtering the list. 
Below is the code for reference
Please let me know if my question makes sense. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
if (propertyName == "Property1")
                {
                    FilteredList = CurrentList.Where(x => x.property1== propertyValue.ToString()).ToList();
                }
                else if (propertyName == "Property2")
                {
                    FilteredList = CurrentList.Where(x => x.property2== propertyValue.ToString()).ToList();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

a. Reflection (if values of propertyName match actual property names)

```
var t = typeof(...your type...);
var pi = t.GetProperty(propertyName);

CurrentFilterList = AfterFilterList
      .Where(x => pi.GetValue(x).ToString() == propertyValue)
      .ToList();
```

b. If property names don't match, then you could try this:

```
var funcs = new Dictionary<string, Func<your_type, object>> 
{
   {"Company", v => v.Company},
   {"InspectionUnit", v => v.InspectionUnit}
};

var f = funcs[propertyName];
CurrentFilterList = AfterFilterList
   .Where(x => f(x) == propertyValue.ToString()).ToList();
```

Code may be inaccurate but should show the idea. #2 should have better performance.

BTW `funcs` could be built dynamically using reflection as well -- just iterate through all props and create funcs / expressions on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that creates the Where condition without reflection. Just for the sake of illustration, if the property name isn't recognized it returns a condition that always returns true - in other words, no filter. An exception might make more sense in response to unrecognized input.

```
private Func<Thing, bool> GetCondition(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "Company":
            return thing => thing.Company == propertyValue;
        case "InspectionUnit":
            return thing => thing.InspectionUnit == propertyValue;
        default: return thing => true;
    }
}
```

Here's a version that uses reflection. As long as we're going this route there's no need to restrict the property to `string` values. It could be anything as long as the `Equals` is implemented, which will be true for strings and value types.

```
private Func<Thing, bool> GetCondition<TSourceType, TPropertyType>
    (string propertyName, TPropertyType propertyValue)
{
    var property = typeof(TSourceType).GetProperty(
        propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    if (property?.PropertyType != typeof(TPropertyType))
        return thing => true; // or throw an exception.
    return thing => property.GetValue(thing).Equals(propertyValue);
}
```

For performance it would be beneficial to store the reflected property in something like a `Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>>` so that for any given type and property name you can look it up instead of repeating the reflection.

**Between the two, I would lean toward *not* using reflection in a your scenario if you're really just looking at a handful of possible values and you're dealing with known types.**

Now the usage would be

Non-generic/non-reflection

```
var condition = GetCondition(propertyName, propertyValue);
var filtered = unfiltered.Where(condition);
```

generic/reflection

```
var condition = GetCondition<Thing, string>(propertyName, propertyValue);
var filtered = unfiltered.Where(condition);
```

---

When I mention storing properties in a dictionary, that's something like this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>> _properties = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>>();

private PropertyInfo GetProperty(Type sourceType, string propertyName)
{
    if(!_properties.ContainsKey(sourceType))
        _properties.Add(sourceType, new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>());
    if (_properties[sourceType].ContainsKey(propertyName))
        return _properties[sourceType][propertyName];
    var property = sourceType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    _properties[sourceType].Add(propertyName, property);
    return property; // could be null;
}
```

But again, that's all just to give an example. It's massive overkill for the scenario you're describing.